# Which Stack Exchange site handles morality-based questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am having some questions based on morality, such as which is right or wrong, etc. I checked the list of available Stack Exchange sites and could find any.

Examples:

> Explain a real-life experience and ask like below...
>
> Why do people cheat?
>
> What is the motivation behind lying/bullying?

Are these kind of questions valid somewhere on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com) can be a good place to post such questions. The site [is described as](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/tour):

> a question and answer site for researchers, academics, students, and enthusiasts needing expert answers to advanced questions in the "cognitive sciences": i.e. cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry.

More specifically, you can ask those under the tag [moral-psychology](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moral-psychology), described as:

> For questions about the neural and psychological processes underlying moral reasoning, moral development, and the psychology of morality in general. Questions about whether something IS moral is a philosophical question, and will often not be suited to this site.

However, a question like *Explain a real-life experience and ask like below...* is not likely to be on topic in any site, since it is clearly too broad and outside the Q&A format that Stack Exchange uses.

Answer (score 4):

- Formal and semi-formal questions about morality and ethics can be posted on [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions about utilitarianism, rule-based ethics, and virtue ethics are acceptable, as are questions about how various philosophers have approached certain ethical issues.
- Practical questions regarding getting along with others can be asked on [Interpersonal Skills.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This can include questions about how to interact with people who have a different ethical system than you, how to evaluate someone's ethical system, and what types of behaviors are commonly considered ethical or unethical according to a specific culture.
- Questions related to ethics as they specifically relate to the academic world (research, study, and teaching) can be asked on [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) with the [ethics] tag. This can include things like how to handle honor code violations, when and how to report misconduct, and what is typically considered misconduct.
- Questions related to workplace ethics can be asked on [The Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

For *all* these sites, please view the help center (and especially it's on-topic guidance that I have linked to above) so that you can post an acceptable question. Many of your sample questions, as written, would be *too broad* on many or all of these sites.

Comment: I hope Interpersonal SE and Workplace SE are giving answers **which works** in that context, **not** necessarily right or wrong.